# How to test web application performance from other continent?

Tags: performance, web-applications

We are hosting our web application http://timr.com on a server located in Germany. The server handles a high load of traffic very well and everything works as desired in terms of performance and load times.

However we sometimes get **complaints from our overseas** users (US, South America) that the experience slow page loading times.

What would be the best way to test the performance of a web application "as if you are on another continent"? I want to make sure that the **distance between the server and the user** is no problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [WebPagetest](http://www.webpagetest.org/) or [Pingdom's Full Page Test](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/) to do one-off testing for free. Pingdom also lets you do continuous testing for a fee.

**Edit**

An ad for Watchmouse showed up in the sidebar. They have a [free site test](http://www.watchmouse.com/en/checkit.php) and paid monitoring plans similar to Pingdom.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Gomez](http://www.gomez.com/instant-test-pro/).

Answer (score 0):

Using something like [PastMON](http://pastmon.sourceforge.net/Wikka-1.1.6.5/wikka.php?wakka=HomePage) will allow you to get accurate measurements of real RTT and bandwidth.

Have a look at [this question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614795/simulate-delayed-and-dropped-packets-on-linux) for how to simulate low bandwidth and/or high latency links. To automate testing have a look at [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/).

[Yahoo Boomerang](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/06/performance_testing_with_boomerang/) is great tool for measuring page response times. Add [graphite](http://codeascraft.etsy.com/2011/02/15/measure-anything-measure-everything/) for capturing / presenting the data.